# Javascript Guessing Game - Counter Not Working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a Javascript guessing game where the user has 10 tries to guess a number between 1-999. I have to use a validate the number, use a loop and show alerts if the user gets a match and also when they run out of guesses. Using the number 45 just for testing. Each guess should be numbered and displayed using innerHTML. Problem is, the counter is stuck at zero. Not sure what I'm missing! Code below:

```
function myFunction() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var randomNum = 45;
  // test for valid input number from 1 to 999
  if (userInput < 0 || userInput > 999) {
    alert("Your number must be from 1 to 999");
  } else {
    alert("Input OK");
  }
  var counter = 0;
  while (counter < 10) {
    counter++;
    if (userInput == randomNum) {
      alert("You win!");
    }
    if (userInput > randomNum) {
      document.getElementById("loopResults").innerHTML += counter + "." + " Your answer: " + userInput + "." + " Guess lower! < br / > ";
      alert("You have " + counter + " guesses left.");
    } else if (userInput < randomNum) {
      document.getElementById("loopResults").innerHTML += counter + "." + " Your answer: " + userInput + "." + "Guess higher! < br / > ";
      alert("You have " + counter + " guesses left.");
    }
    break;
  } // end while loop
} // end function myFunction()
```

Comment: `break` ends `while` loop. __always__ You should think where to put it/

Comment: put the break in an else at the end.

Comment: The break isn't the biggest issue, the counter variable being function scoped is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
var counter = 0;
```

resets counter to 0 every time the function is called. One fix could be to set this as a global variable in this way

```
counter = 0; // note no var keyword
function myFunction() {...}
```

Then your calls to counter in the function will reference the global variable.

In addition, your while loop doesn't make sense. It should be a simple if statement to see if counter >= 10. Think about this logic after counter variable is being set correctly.

Comment: Thank you! This helped get the counter moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Step through the logic in your while loop.

The counter variable incrementing in each loop will already cause your loop to exit.

Setting a "break" at the end of the while loop means that you are guaranteed to exit after the first

Comment: Thanks! Question for you...I added the break at the end, because otherwise, all the alerts pop up one after the other with no pause to take another guess. Not understanding how to get it to start over again?

Comment: You'd want to embed another opportunity for the user to input a guess so you can check the conditions all over again.

I imagine it'd go like

while you have guesses left, check if they got it right, if no, tell them how many guesses they have left and prompt them again to input a number

Comment: alternatively, you could separate your game logic without a while loop. After they input a guess, check the counter variable and increment. Have a condition where if they reach the counter limit, you then tell them that they lost

Comment: btw if this is helpful, I'd appreciate you marking as solved :)

Comment: Sure thing! Just have to figure out where to do this...still new to this site. :) Thanks!

Comment: Np! Thanks robin. I think it's the checkmark underneath the numbers on the side ;)

Answer (score 1):

Only `break` your loop when you actually want to exit it. In your case, that would probably be when the user has guessed the number or is out of tries.

The `break` command immediately ends the loop. Have a look at [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) for more info!